# C++ getting keypad pad key press only if keyboard has been pressed

Tags: c++, getch

I'm trying to set this function up so that it waits for the user to press a key on the keypad and then returns the number that they pressed.

This is what I've got but it seems to be allowing anything to be returned.

```
int numpad(int min, int max) {
  int input;
  do {
    input=getch() - 48;
  }
  while(input<=min && input>=max);
  return input;
}
```

Anyone know what's going wrong here?

Comment: What's intended to do with `while(input<=min && input>=max)`?

Comment: say min=0 and max=9. it checks if the key pressed is one of the wanted numerical values.

Comment: My god! How did you suppose it's CSS or a JavaScript snippet?!

Comment: Please try to avoid the use of [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If by `48` you mean the [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) encoded character `'0'` then *say* so. That will also make the code portable (there are systems which doesn't use ASCII).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Don't worry. This guy's obviously programming for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wrote a wrong token:

```
while(input<=min && input>=max);
                 ^^
```

Which should have been

```
while(input< min || input> max);
            ^    ^^       ^
```